# Dynamic views in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, view, observablecollection

I'm trying to dynamically change `UserControl` views that are defined in an `ObservableCollection`.

```
public class MItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private UserControl _mView;
        public UserControl MView
        {
            get { return _mView; }
            set
            {
                if (_mView != value)
                {
                    _mView = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MView");
                }
            }
        }

...
        }
```

In a separate view I have:

```
ObservableCollection<MItem> _items = new ObservableCollection<MItem>;

_items.Add(new MItem{MView = MyView});
```

Obviously when it comes to create a new object of that view and then assigning it to a child on a Grid comes to be a problem - It'll give me a type error.

I've tried something like:

```
_items[0].MView = new UserControl(); // I know this wouldn't work
```

My main question is, has anyone tried implementing something like this and how did you get around it?

Thanks

Comment: This goes against everything MVVM stands for. You should not have references to any UI elements in an `ObservableCollection`. Create an `ObservableCollection<SomeViewModel>` instead and then use proper `DataTemplates` to render these on screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @HighCore indicates, WPF allows for a much better way of dynamically determining what view to display, while maintaining a separation of concerns so you're not mixing view logic with business logic.  And MVVM is the tried and true method of accomplishing this.

Essentially, what you want to do is create a ViewModel for each "thing" you want to display.  Then, you create a `DataTemplate` for each ViewModel which is the View.  The `DataTemplate` could be self contained, or it could just point to a `UserControl`.  Then, you use a `ContentPresenter` which is DataBound to a CurrentItem property, or something, and when you set the CurrentItem to a specific ViewModel, WPF will locate the appropriate `DataTemplate` (View) for you and display it accordingly.

There are several walkthroughs on the web that demonstrate this, and there are also several examples of this pattern on StackOverflow as well.  One example that seems to match very closely what you're asking for is here: [Switching between Views/UserControls using MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/).

Comment: Thanks Brian, that helps me understand how my solution will work the **proper** way.

Comment: @BrianS Taking the example from the article you shared, if the Window with the ContentPresenter has a ViewModel and that ContentPresenter is responsible for displaying Views (each with their own ViewModels): 1) Can the Window's ViewModel get/set details on the displayed View's Viewmodel? 2) If so, how would one "talk" to the displayed View's ViewModel?

Comment: @IsaiahNelson, sorry I never responded to this, just noticed your question.  You've probably already gotten answers to this question, but the answer to both 1 and 2 is DataBinding & `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  The View will DataBind to the ViewModel, which causes the View to subscribe to property changes (through `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`).  Then, by setting properties on the ViewModel, the View is automatically informed of those changes, and will update to reflect the new values.